# html forms and php populate from Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a html form that is populated by a mysql query.    The data has spaces in it.

eg "Bob site", "Sarah home"

When the form is created in the browser I get this:
Bob
site
Sarah
home

Instead of
Bob site
Sarah home.

I know I need to format my data but can't find any examples.  My form code is below.

```
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
<?php
$site = mysql_query("select distinct `site_name` from sept_billing");
?>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Create a new install</h2>
    <form method="post" action="actions/newmachine_action.php">
        <table border = '0'>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Site name:</b></td>
                <td><input id="site" type="text" name="site"  size="40" list="sites" value = 'Choose site name' />
                    <datalist id="sites">
                        <?php
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($site))
                        {
                            echo "<option value=".$row[0].">";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </datalist></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: In which browser are you checking ? It will not display in some of the browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this and let me know if this works

```
echo "<option value=".$row[0].">";
```

to

```
echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

> This will work

```
                <?php
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($site))
                    { ?>

                       <option><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>

               <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"<option text='".$row[0]."' value='".preg_replace(' ', '-', $row[0])."'></option>"
```

or

```
"<option value='".preg_replace(' ', '-', $row[0])."'>".$row[0]."</option>"
```

i think that value cannot have spaces